# Working with .csv data as a Pandas DataFrame, getting redundancy error when applying logic

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Been working on this project all day and it's destroying me. Currently have finished web scraping and have a final .csv which contains the elements of a pandas dataframe. Working with this dataframe in a new file, and currently have the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv('active_homes.csv')

for i in range(len(df)):
    add = df['Address'][i]
    price = df['Price'][i]
    if (price<100000) == True:
        print(price)
```

'**active_homes.csv**' looks like this:

Address,Status,Price,Meta

"387 8th St, Burlington, CO 80807",For Sale,169500,"4bed2bath1,560sqft"

,and the resulting df's **shape** is (1764, 4).

This should, in theory, print the price for each iteration of price<100000.

In practice, it prints this:

[image: example terminal output]

I have confirmed that at each iteration of the above for loop, it is collecting the correct 'Price' and 'Address' information, and have also confirmed that at each interval the logic (price<100000) is working correctly. However, it is still doing the above. I was originally trying to just drop the rows of the dataframe that were <100000 but that wasn't doing anything. I was also trying to reassign the data to a new dataframe and it would either return an empty dataframe, or return a dataframe with duplicate data of this house (with the 'Price' of 58900).

So far, from all of that, I believe that the program is recognizing the amount of correct houses < 100000, but for some reason the assignment is sticking for the one address. It also does the same thing without assignment, as in:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if (df['Price'][i]<100000) == True:
        print(df['Price'][i])
```

Any help in identifying the error would be much appreciated.

Comment: what about `df.loc[df['Price'].lt(100000)]`?

Comment: results of df.loc[df['Price'].lt(100000)]  are that I'm getting the same error unfortunately, but just getting the full df with it. although i do like that logic better, something is fucked. resulting df looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/60WfoxT

Answer (score 0):

With Pandas you try to never iterate everything in the traditional python way. Instead, you could achieve the desired result using the following method:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('active_homes.csv')

temp_df = df[df["Price"]<100000] # initiating a new df isn't required, just a force of a habit
print(temp_df["Price"]) # displaying a series of houses that are below 100K; imo prettier print
```

Comment: resulting dataframe looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/60WfoxT   

same error, just have the full df now. although i do appreciate the suggestion on pandas iteration.

Comment: that's not really how it should look, did you copy the code? I'll update mine just copy paste it

can you also show the dtype of your df? `df.dtypes`

Comment: took a screenshot of the new results, I didn't copy/paste but the only thing I forgot was the temp_df['Price'] part. dtype is int64, also viewable at the bottom of the screenshot. link to results here: https://imgur.com/a/wPLH3MG

Comment: Could you please fully copy the code and show the results? there is something that sets the values to 58900 or that value is leaking from one row to populate your full df

Comment: Yep, figured it out a few minutes ago. I was pulling my hair out but it was an earlier assignment I had been using, that ended up scraping the same page repeatedly creating dupes. Didn't end up needing to change the iteration method, the issue was my own fault, but I do appreciate your help. Cheers!

Comment: @SamuelTroyer Then either close the question or grant the answer.